# Rabbitmq high availability queues without message replication

Tags: rabbitmq

I have rabbitMQ broker running on two nodes as a cluster. I have observed that if node, where queue have been created, goes down, then queue would not be available on other node. If I try to publish a message from other node it fails. Even if I remove the failed node from cluster(using forget cluster command) and try to publish message from other node, the behavior is same.

I dont want to enable mirroring of the queue for the simple reason that it would replicate the messages which would be additional load on inter-network.

Is there way available in rabbitMQ to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour you are experiencing is the default behaviour of rabbitmq and its exactly what i supposed to happen.The node where you created the queue becomes the producer now and if this node goes down then any connection available to it or queues or exchanges associated with it will not work at all. There are two options to resolve this issue.

- One option is that there is one separate queue for every node and any node that wants to listen to receive messages from a particular node can subscribe to that particular queue's exchange. This seems to be not a very good idea since you need to manage a lot of things for it.
- Second option is to always declare a queue before you publish so if your queue is not available then a new queue would take its place and all the nodes subscribe to would be able to listen and any producer node will be able to post that queue. This option will resolve the problems of node getting down or node not available. from the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)

> before sending we need to make sure the recipient queue exists. If we send a message to non-existing location, RabbitMQ will just drop the message. Let's create a hello queue to which the message will be delivered:

Answer (score -1):

RabbitMQ lets you import and export *definitions*. Definitions are json files which contain  all broker objects (queues, exchanges, bindings, users, virtual hosts, permissions and parameters). They do not include the messages of queues.

You can export definitions of the node who owns the queue and import them to the slave node of the cluster periodically. You have to enable the management plugin for this task.

More information here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#configuration